What is the simplest formula for calculating the circumference of a circle?
I am studying for a test to become a "paraeducator/instructional aid." One of the pages in the study guide has this information on computing area and perimeter and circumference and such:

Wouldn't it be simpler to say "multiply the diameter by pi"?

It depends on what value you have, or which you want to parameterize by. Using the diameter of an existing circle is probably easier when measuring with a ruler, but when creating the circle with a compass, the radius is more natural.

Using the diameter $d=2r$ makes the circumference formula exactly one symbol shorter, while it turns the area formula into e.g. $A=\frac{\pi d^2}{4}$.

I give you a piece of rope and a pen and order you to draw a circle. Most probably you will hold one side of the rope with your one hand and attach the pen at the other side, put your one hand down on the table, stretch the rope, move the pen and draw the circle. The length of that rope is the radius. Like this, it's very easy to understand how basic the understanding of the radius of a circle is.

2 pi or not 2 pi, that is the question.

Are you interested in the simplest mathematical method or are you interested at the simplest teaching method? These two things are not always the same.

As an aside, "there are 360 degrees in a circle" is one of those imprecise statements which people know the meaning of without considering what it actually says. An angle is between two lines; what does it mean for an angle to be "in a circle"? There are other things on this sheet to take issue with: bisect means to find the midpoint of a line or half of an angle; pi is not equal to 3.14; the three angles of a triangle add to 180 degrees, but do not each add to 180 degrees. Clear thinking is more important than facial simplicity.

I believe the simplest formula for the circumference is "the circumference". Just input the value, and there you have it. Number of arithmetic operations is zero. It all boils down to "what do you know already". If all you know is the area of the circle, then the simplest possible formula is something else.

I am shocked that this questions has received so many upvotes when it is so fruitless. Can someone explain to me the difference between learning or teaching $\pi d$ and $2\pi r?$ or learning/teaching that both formulae exist? Is this really any more difficult than giving the shopkeeper two 50 pence coins rather than one £1 coin? Maybe I am not reading the question correctly?

I’m voting to close this question because it seems fruitless. Students should probably memorise one formula and be able to derive the other from the one they memorised. But a small amount of solving circles questions should fix whatever memorisation problems they have.

Conservation of Difficulty
You should not be focused on what formula is "simpler".  I have often joked with colleagues that mathematics has a kind of Law of Conservation of Difficulty:  any particular problem has a certain difficulty associated to it, and there is not really any way of getting around that difficulty.  My usual go-to example of this is a proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra:  there are very elementary proofs which basically boil down to gradient descent, and fancier proofs which rely on Liouville's theorem.
The elementary proofs are typically very long and tedious—because an elementary proof uses elementary tools, there are no big theorems which can be used to make the proof shorter or "simpler"—one must simply brute force the problem.  On the other hand, a proof using Liouville is a two liner—but one has to spend a lot of time building up the theory of complex analysis before getting to a proof of Liouville so that one can then proceed to prove the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.  The difficulty of the proof can be moved to a different place, but it can't be entirely removed.
As an instructor, it is your job to take complicated ideas and find a path through those ideas which will develop the theory in a coherent manner, so that the steps from one idea to the next will each appear simple, until you have a chance to zoom out or look back and see the material taught in total.
An Ahistorical History
In geometry, a circle is defined by two things:  a point $C$ (the center of the circle) and a distance $r$ (the radius of the circle). By definition, the circle with center $C$ and radius $r$ is the set of points which are exactly $r$ units from $C$.  In classical Euclidean geometry, this makes sense, since one of the basic tools is the compass, which can be used to construct a circle in exactly the manner described above, the center and radius are fundamental.
This implies that any formula relating to a circle should start from these two data:  the center and the radius.  After some investigation, we learn that the circumference of a circle is proportional to the radius.  That is, there exists some constant $k$ such that the circumference $P$ of a circle with radius $r$ is
$$ P = kr. $$
A bit more work shows that $k \approx 6.28$.  This number shows up in a lot of places, so one might want to go ahead and give it a name:  $\tau ≈ 6.28$ is, by definition, the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius.
However, in the real world, measuring the radius of a circle is a bit of a pain—one has to find the center of the circle, and then measure the radius.  It turns out that it is easier to measure the diameter (e.g. with calipers; or by constructing a chord and considering a perpendicular bisector of that chord).  So, from a practical point of view, it is often easier to get one's hands on the diameter, $D$, of a circle.  The diameter is twice the radius, so another formula for the circumference of a circle is
$$ P = \tau \frac{D}{2} = \frac{\tau}{2} D. $$
Because the term $\tau/2$ appears repeatedly, it might be wise to give this a name, too.  So define
$$ \pi = \frac{\tau}{2} = \frac{\text{circumference}}{\text{diameter}} \approx 3.14. $$
At the end of the day, there are two (equivalent) formulae for the circumference of a circle:
$$ P = \pi D \qquad\text{and}\qquad P = 2\pi r. $$
The former is, perhaps, more practical (because it is, maybe, easier to measure a diameter); but the latter is more fundamental, as it relates directly to the construction of the circle in terms of a center and radius.
The Language of Mathematics
Another job of an instructor is to teach students the language used in their field.  In mathematics,

one "multiplies two numbers" (one does not "times two numbers);
one "evaluates an integral" (one does not "solve an integral);
one "solves a polynomial equation" and "determines [or finds] the zeros of a polynomial function" (one does not "solve a function");
and so on.

The use of the radius in the formula for the circumference of a circle is a matter of correct mathematical "spelling" or "grammar"—it is the correct way to use language as mathematicians use that language.  Whether or not it is "more simple" (which, as I have argued above, it really isn't), it is how the language is used, and students need to get used to that use of language.
This is particularly important, as there are many, many other places in mathematics where the radius plays a role.  In three-dimensional geometry, it shows up in the formulae for the volume and surface area of a sphere; it is fundamental to the definitions of the cosine and sine functions as functions on $\mathbb{R}$; and so on.  The radius shows up everywhere in the language of mathematics, so one might as well get students used to this as early as possible.

Tangential Note:  In the formula sheet quoted in the question, it is asserted that $\pi = 3.14$.  This is wrong—don't say this to students; $\pi$ is not equal to $3.14$.  This is a reasonable approximation for $\pi$ in most circumstances, but there is no equality here.  The constant $\pi$ is irrational—it does not have a terminating or repeating decimal expansion.  It is totally reasonable to tell students that $\pi \approx 3.14$, but be clear that this is an approximation, not an equality.

"in the real world, measuring the radius of a circle is a bit of a pain" ─ true, but also constructing a circle of a given radius is easier than constructing a circle of a given diameter. So which formula for computing the circumference is more practical, depends on if it is a circle you found (and must measure), vs. a circle you constructed.

@kaya3 Sure... but I don't think that I made a definitive statement.  I think what I said is that measuring the diameter is often more practical (not that it is always more practical).  In the "real world", we really want both formulae, which is why they both exist.

You could say: $\tau r$.
Circles are defined geometrically by their radius (note it has precedence before diameter in the study guide), so a lot of formulas would be conceptually more meaningful, and often simpler, if the radius was in the picture. On the other hand, real-world circles are arguably easier to measure via the rim-to-rim diameter. As a result, we've gotten in the historically unfortunate habit of shifting a factor of $2$ from the circle constant to the circle measure.
A lot of people now note that many formulas would be simplified if the circle constant used was $\tau = 2 \pi$. E.g., that's the number of radians in one full circle (whereas $\pi$ only gets you halfway around). And then like many other formulas, here you're looking at a factor of $r$, which is more fundamental than the diameter in the definition of a circle (e.g., as in the area formula immediately prior in the given study guide).
This larger story is probably why the study guide prefers to see $r$ in the formula. It's part of other circle-based formulas (as opposed to diameter), so students should be most familiar with it.
See more at: The Tau Manifesto.

Seems unfortunate that the constant with a larger value is denoted by a letter lacking a leg. I think ᲅ, or even better ന്ന or  to properly reflect the doubling, would be more suitable.

@Ruslan: Helps to think of it as a denominator. Tau is $1$ circle, pi is $1 \over 2$ circle.

It is a matter of taste. But there are some reasons for this preference.

It is easiest to use either the radius or the diameter and to stick with it. There is less conversion, so less mental load and less room for error. So given that we absolutely want this to be the case and we also only consider the formulas for area and circumference, we would have to choose between $A=\pi r^2$ and $C=2\pi r$ or $A=\tfrac 1 4\pi D^2$ and $C=\pi D$. Just from these formulas I would not say there is a clear winner.
How about other dimensions? We can do the same comparison for higher dimensions and compare which expressions look nicer.



The formulas using $r$ behave better when the number of dimensions get larger. When using the diameter in 6D, one of the coefficients  is 384, yuck!

When you start doing calculus, at some point you will likely calculate the area of a circle using integration. For that you will use some form of the formula $x^2+y^2\leq r^2$. Not only is the radius a clear winner here in terms of computation, conceptually it is also easier to define it in terms of radius. The formula $x^2+y^2\leq r^2$ is also used a lot in programming.

So to summarise, the decision is kind of arbitrary. But some considerations that come from more "advanced" uses, combined with a fair bit of historical bagage, manage to tip the scale towards the radius in favor of the diameter. There are some things to be said though for the diameter. First of all, $\pi$ is often defined as the ratio between the circumference of the circle and its diameter, i.e. $\pi=C/D$. Also, in some areas in physics (for example soft matter) the size of spheres is defined using the diameter instead of the radius.
For those interested, I used the following Mathematica code to create the tables:
TableForm[
 Table[{ToString[d] <> "D", (2*Pi^(d/2)*r^(-1 + d))/
    Gamma[d/2], (Pi^(d/2)*r^d)/Gamma[1 + d/2]}, {d, 1, 10}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"Dim.", "Area", "Volume"}}]


Apologies for the commenty-answer, but have not seen this aspect raised yet:
In no way, wanting to cut you off from wondering about math or the like.  But you should concentrate on teaching the standard methods, content, notation, etc.  Especially as an "aide".  But even if you were a head of the NYC public schools or the like.
There are plenty of more important issues like how to teach fractions or keep control in the classroom.  (And these are non-trivial!)
Of course, every question can't (and shouldn't) be on the highest priority topic.  But I just want to warn you.

Given an arc-length of $l$ which represents a proportion, $p$ of the circle, the circumference is $\frac{l}{p}$. For example, if an arc-length is $1$ and that represents $\frac{1}{3}$ of the circle, then the circumference is 3.
Some may scoff at division being "simpler," but with just 2 terms, no constants to remember, and no $\pi :\tau$ debates, $\frac{l}{p}$ is hard to ignore.

But if you have the means to directly measure an arc-length and know exactly what fraction of the circle it is, then you have the means to directly measure the circumference and not need this formula at all. :P

@Idran I must have misread the title of question!

Well, the fun fact is, diameter does not "exist" in math. All formulas are defined in terms of radius r.
The only time you will see diameter d mentioned is in the formula introducing concept of Pi (ratio of circumference to diameter)
Another fun fact is that you will see that "2 Pi" pop up in majority of formulas. Truly, it would be more convenient to have a constant of value 2 Pi (*).
(*)Which we actually have, look for Tau Manifesto.

I very much disagree.  The diameter of a set exists.  For a circle, the diameter is exactly twice the radius.  Otherwise, the diameter of $A$ (where $A$ is some subset of a metric space) is $\sup{d(x,y): x,y\in A}$ (i.e. it is the greatest distance between any two points in the space).  This notion of diameter is extremely important in some contexts, e.g. in the definition of the Hausdorff measure.  There are also interesting questions about the diameter, e.g. "are there any non-circular shapes with constant diameter?"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width

Neither of those "exist" in pre-university math, thus they do not "exist" for majority of people. Of course the term "diameter" will pop-up in math somewhere, because math is big field and always short on words. But consider the term only appears once in pre-calculus math - when defining Pi. I also find it funny that the article you link to prove diameter is used is actually using the term "width" throughout. We should be using width for circles, that sounds right. No need to have specific name for longest chord that passes through center point.

You are moving the goalposts.  In your answer, you assert that "diameter does not 'exist' in math".  When I demonstrated that the diameter manifestly does "exist" in mathematics, you change the argument. Now you are asserting that (1)  it only "exists" once in pre-calculus, and that (2) the majority of people will won't need to know anything about the diameter.

Regarding (1), the diameter shows up a lot in high-school geometry.  There are some interesting theorems related to the diameter, e.g. if the endpoints of a diameter are joined to any other point on the circle, the triangle produced is a right triangle (Thales' Theorem).  Note that this is one example---I am not giving me because space in comments is limited.

(2) From a practical point of view, the diameter is actually more commonly used outside of mathematics.  Formulae related to the diameter are more helpful, as the tool used to measure circles in the real world is typically a set of calipers (e.g. for measuring pipe).

Finally, you seem to argue that we should use some other word, instead, e.g. "width".  The problem with that is that "diameter" (like "circumference", which is really just the perimeter) is already used all over the place, and part of teaching students is teaching them to recognize the language being used.  "Diameter" is used enough in the "real world" that it does a disservice to students to pretend that it doesn't exist.

@XanderHenderson Please go back to the first line of my answer and notice the quotes around "exists". I am not claiming that diameter as a term dos not exist in whole body of the math (that would be easy to disprove). What I am saying is that the term is fairly nonexistent for an average person who did not take math courses or finish higher education.
Secondly, I am poking fun at a diameter as a term, for its scarcity in basic math formulas (radius is used everywhere).
Thirdly, I find the term "width" from article you mentioned a perfectly good replacement for casual use. Pipes have width.

Diameter both exists and "exists."
